# Lenovo Thinkpad W500 - fruit pulp got in around docking socket, black screen

Tags: thinkpad

Banana pulp got into the laptop through the docking socket area. Already disassembled the laptop, and cleaned as much pulp as I can see from the bottom side of the motherboard, as well as surrounding area.

When connecting AC without battery, the power light and cord lights are on, battery flashing, caps lock and num lock come on and off as normal, but screen stays black.
Same with battery.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly shorted something out, best to let a professional take a look at it.

Comment: You can take a look at the [ThinkPad T500 and W500
Hardware Maintenance Manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/43y6630_03.pdf) for ideas. 1. How did banana pulp get into the _bottom_ of the machine?? 2. What happens when you connect an external monitor? 3. It's been two years. Do you still have the machine? Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.